# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException using Android Studio with Google Drive

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-api

I have my Android Studio project files stored in Google Drive. The newer versions of Google Drive (version 62+) do not seem to behave very well with Android Studio.

Whilst Google Drive is active and syncing on my PC, and I try to deploy or build an Android project, I get Build failed with the AccessDeniedException error below.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: G:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:110)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1181)...
```

It always seems to be the build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values folder which Android Studio does not have access to, while Google Drive is in use and syncing files.

If I pause the syncing of Google Drive, then there is no issue and everything works fine. I am also aware 'Clean Project' and 'Invalidate Caches and Restart' will resolve this issue, but it's not very conducive to working when I have to do this every time I want to deploy the app.

The older versions of Google Drive (where it didn't create dedicated local drives) worked fine.
I also used to have my project files in Dropbox and that also works fine. The issue only seems to be with the newer versions of Google Drive 62+.

Is there any setting I could look at or a way to prevent this from occurring? I want to have the old functionality back where I could build/deploy without issues using Google Drive as my project storage location. Thanks.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue but in my case, I mirrored my google drive account to a local folder. The step I took to resolve this issue is to delete the `.gradle` folder and build again.

Comment: @maddy23285 thanks yes that seemed to work. I had my drive mirrored to a local folder already, so I deleted the .gradle folder of the project and then had to clean project one last time, now it seems to be behaving well.